# InputmenthodService of custom keyboard changed to Phone'sdefault when Reboot or update app

Tags: keyboard, android-softkeyboard, keyboard-events, android-input-method, custom-keyboard

Created Full Functional custom keyboard and working almost all phones but when checking to Asus (kitkat Android 4.4.4) phone and MI(note 2) It gives some Problem.

**Changed to Default Phone's Keyboard when:**

1. Phone restarts.
2. Application Updates.
3. Clear App from multitasking window.

when checked to Other keyboards like [go Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.emoji.gokeyboard) and others from google playstore it works fine.

by observation it looks like inputmethodservice disconnecting so that default connection is set. if someone have idea about problem or make stable connection with inputMethodService .?? help me.